# Get JSON property name followed by item name values using PHP

Tags: php, json, object

I am trying to parse through a JSON using PHP then print the name of the parent property followed by the items.

Here's the JSON

```
{
"Specials": [{
    "name": "Shirt","dsc":"cotton shirt",
    "vari": [{ "name":"red", "price":25.80 },{ "name":"green", "price":26.50 }]
}, 

{
    "name":"shorts","dsc":"one size","price":15.99
},

{
    "name":"shoes","dsc":"black shoes",
    "vari": [{ "name":"capri", "price":37.80 },{ "name":"shooters", "price":28.50 }]
}],

"Jumpers": [{
    "name": "Glax Red","dsc":"thin lightweight","price":22.99
}, 

{
    "name": "Bazoo Care","dsc":"ideal for winter","price":32.99
}]
}
```

I have used following to iterate through it:

```
$readjson = file_get_contents('products.json') ;

$data = json_decode($readjson);

foreach ($data as $products) {
foreach ($products as $product) {

echo $product->name."<br>".$product->dsc."<br>";
if (isset($product->price))
    {
echo " ".$product->price."<br>";
}
else {
foreach ($product->vari as $var) {
echo $var->name." ".$var->price."<br/>";
}
}
```

The output is:

**Shirt**
*cotton shirt*
red 25.8
green 26.5
**shorts**
*one size*
15.99
...

I'd like to print the name of the property first then show the items that are within it, it should look like this:

Specials

**Shirt**
*cotton shirt*
red 25.8
green 26.5

**shorts**
*one size*
15.99
...

Jumpers

**Glax Red**
*thin lightweight*
22.99

**Bazoo Care**
*ideal for winter*
32.99

I've added this as the outer nested loop:

```
foreach ($data as $products => $value) {
echo $products;}
```

But that only returns the first object name. How can I achieve the above?

Here's a visualisation of the JSON.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to output the key name in the first loop, so

```
foreach ($data as $products) {
```

Is the bit which loops over the items `Specials` etc. So first grab the key in the `foreach()` and just output this as the first thing in the loop...

```
foreach ($data as $key => $products) {
    echo $key."<br>";
```

(No `}`)
Will give...

```
Specials<br>Shirt<br>cot...
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert you `json` to array and loop through it

```
 $data = json_decode($readjson, true);
```

Here we are passing `true` parameter which means an array without object.

```
foreach($data as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $k => $v){
     echo '<b>'.$v['name'].'</b> '.' '.$v['dsc'];
     echo isset($v['price']) ? $v['price'] : ' ';
     if(array_key_exists('vari', $v)){
        $vari = array_column($v['vari'], 'price','name');
        foreach($vari as $_k => $_v){
            echo $_k.' '.$_v;
        }
     }
     echo '<hr>';
  }
}
```

Result:-

```
Shirt cotton shirt red 25.8green 26.5
shorts one size15.99
shoes black shoes capri 37.8shooters 28.5
Glax Red thin lightweight22.99
Bazoo Care ideal for winter32.99
```